# How can I get a specific range of bytes in the varbinary data?

Tags: t-sql

How can I get a specific range of bytes in the `varbinary` data?

For example length of `varbinary` data is 128 and I want to get only 15-19 bytes.

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(VarbinaryColumn, 15, 5)
```

`15` being the first position and `5` the length.

More information:

- [SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Comment: @aF.: Thanks, would be nice to know what particularly is/can be wrong with this.

Comment: well after some testing it works but I've a doubt. What datatype does that substring returns?

Comment: @aF. usually input type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx and SUBSTRING does works with varbinary. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1289171/27535 from Remus

Comment: It returns `varbinary(5)`. Here's a test script:
`WITH data (v) AS (
SELECT CAST(REPLICATE('a', 20) AS varbinary)
),
data2 (v) AS (
SELECT SUBSTRING(v, LEN(15), 5) FROM data
)
SELECT v, SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(v, 'BaseType'), SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(v, 'MaxLength') FROM data2`